# Check if 2 arrays have the same elements using recursion Java

Tags: java, recursion

i have this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int e[]={1,2,3};
    int f[]={1,2,3};
    int t=e.length-1;

    System.out.println(Recursivo6(e,f,t));
}


public static boolean Recursivo6(int e[], int f[], int t){

    if(t==0) {
        if((e[0]==f[0]) && Recursivo6(e, f, t-1)){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```

but in the method recursivo, the first conditional is not working, it always throws me false, can you help me? thanks.

Comment: What's with the complete lack of indentation?

Comment: Why not use `Arrays.equals()`?

Comment: It'll always be false if you never modify t or the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning false because the condition is (t==0) while t is the length of the array, so it will always return false. Maybe try if (t > 0)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following one-liner:

```
public static boolean Recursivo6(int e[], int f[], int t){
    return ((e[t] == f[t]) && ((t == 0) || (Recursivo6(e, f, t - 1))));
}
```

It starts with `t` being at the end of the arrays. In each iteration, if the elements of the arrays are not equal at the corresponding index, then the second operand of the `&&` will not be evaluated, thus, this part is pretty performant. The second operand of the `&&` is a logical expression, which evaluates as `true` if we are at the end of the algorithm, which is signed by `t` being `0`. If `t` reaches `0`, `Recursivo6` will no longer be called. Otherwise, it is called using a decremented `t`.

Your mistakes:

- your `if` will always be `false` unless you pass `0` as initial `t` value
- you should evaluate the `t`'th elements instead of the `0`'th